Next.js TypeScript Error with chessboard-element on Vercel Deployment
I'm building a chess application using Next.js 14.2.7, TypeScript, and the chessboard-element package. The project builds and runs fine locally, but I'm encountering a TypeScript error when deploying to Vercel.
Failed to compile.

./components/ChessBoard.tsx:76:7
Type error: Property 'chess-board' does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'.

Structure
/
├── src/
│   ├── app/
│   │   └── page.tsx
│   ├── components/
│   │   └── ChessBoard.tsx
│   └── types/
│       └── chessboard.d.ts
├── package.json
└── tsconfig.json

src/components/ChessBoard.tsx

"use client";

import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { Chess } from 'chess.js';
import 'chessboard-element';

const ChessBoard = () => {
  const boardRef = useRef<ChessBoardElement>(null);
  // ... other code ...

  return (
    <div>
      <chess-board ref={boardRef} style={{ width: '400px' }} position="start" draggable-pieces />
      {/* ... other elements ... */}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ChessBoard;


src/types/chessboard.d.ts
import * as React from 'react';

declare global {
  namespace JSX {
    interface IntrinsicElements {
      'chess-board': React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, HTMLElement> & {
        position?: string;
        'draggable-pieces'?: boolean;
      };
    }
  }
}

declare class ChessBoardElement extends HTMLElement {
  setPosition(fen: string): void;
}

tsconfig.json:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "./src/types"],
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx",
    ".next/types/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}

The project builds and runs without errors locally.
I've created a custom type definition file for the chess-board element.
I've updated my tsconfig.json to include the custom type definitions.
All my dependencies are up to date.

I'm not sure if this'll work, but you could try importing the declaration file into a file relevant to the build, or you could try renaming it to global.d.ts. Also consider setting declaration: true in your TS config.
